# HTML data update for XML column with new value in SQL Server

Tags: html, sql-server, xquery

I have some experience in XQuery to update the XML data. I have tried to use the same logic for the HTML data in SQL Server.

But not working as expected.

For example I have a XML column `Value` (actually HTML data) as below.

```
Declare @template xml = '<div>
<div id="divHeader">Congratulation<div id="Salutation">ravi</div></div><br/>
<div>From now you are a part of the Company<div id="cmpnyUserDetails"></div></div><br/>
<div id="clickSection">Please Click <a href="">Here</a> to Access Your New Features</div>
</div>'
```

and I would like change the html value od the div with ID "Salutation" to "New Value" and Append the href value to a valid link using the XQuery.

```
SET @template.modify('replace value of (//div[id=("Salutation")]/text())[1] with "New Value"')
SELECT @template AS data
```

But it's not working.

Can someone please suggest to me how to make it happen?

Thanks a ton in advance,
Ravi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  Notice the `@id` vs. your `id`

**Example**

```
SET @template.modify('replace value of (//div[@id=("Salutation")]/text())[1] with "New Value"')
select @template as data
```

**Returns**

```
<div>
  <div id="divHeader">Congratulation<div id="Salutation">New Value</div></div>
  <br />
  <div>From now you are a part of the Company<div id="cmpnyUserDetails" /></div>
  <br />
  <div id="clickSection">Please Click <a href="">Here</a> to Access Your New Features</div>
</div>
```